# Getting adjacent cell values around the current cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I want to get the adjacent cell values for calculation in VBA.

It is easy to get the left cell of the current cell(e.g.H19) usually like this:

```
=H18
```

If I copy this cell to other cells, each of them is changed to an appropriate cell number.

But in VBA code, I am not sure if I am right to get the value of the left cell.

```
Public Function LeftCell()
    LeftCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
End Function
```

I am not sure this is correct, I tested copying this cell to other cells but each result is not changed automatically.

I clicked all kinds of Calcuation buttons on the Menu, changed Calculation as Automatic, but there is no calculation occur.

The only way I can do is to manually select each cell and press enter.

Is there any way to calculate all cell values? 
Otherwise, "The Active Cell" means "The Selected Cell by Cursor"?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: When you copy the formula by dragging a formula cell, remember the formula cell remains the active cell. If you copy the formula cell with Ctrl+C and paste it in another cell, it will return the correct output based on the active cell as the cell where the formula is being pasted into becomes the next active cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a formula as @Chris Harper suggests would work, but then you may as well just write the formula in the cell.

Rather than the ActiveCell you want the cell that called the formula.

```
Public Function LeftCell()
    LeftCell = Application.Caller.Offset(, -1).Value
End Function
```

Edit:  If you want the cell to update whenever you change the value add `Application.Volatile True` as your first line in the function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx

Comment: Shouldn’t the Function return something? `Public Function LeftCell() As ...`

Comment: I took 6 hours to find the solution, thank you! And thanks for other answers as well. Now I can paste this formula to multiple cells!

Comment: Yes, it should really have a explicit Variant data type to deal with numbers and text (which it does anyway without the variable type declaration - always good practice to make it clear though).  You could wrap the LeftCell line to check the column and return `#REF` if it's column 1 as it's trying to look off the edge of the sheet - `If Application.Caller.Column = 1 Then: LeftCell = CVErr(xlErrRef):Else:LeftCell = .Caller.Offset(,-1).Value:End If`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate method in Excel VBA do all kind of calculations. You can even define a range to calculate only a range of specific cells like Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate.

Yes, ActiveCell is always the Selected Cell.

As an alternative to setting value by Offset, you can use ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"